# Persisting Neo4j transactions to external storage

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I'm currently working on a new Java application which uses an embedded Neo4j database as its data store.  Eventually we'll be deploying to a cloud host which has no persistent data storage available - we're fine while the app is running but as soon as it stops we lose access to anything written to disk.

Therefore I'm trying to come up with a means of persisting data across an application restart.  We have the option of capturing any change commands as they come into our application and writing them off somewhere but that means retaining a lifetime of changes and applying them in order as an application node comes back up.  Is there any functionality in Neo4j or SDN that we could leverage to capture changes at the Neo4j level and write them off to and AWS S3 store or the like?  I have had a look at Neo4j clustering but I don't think that will work either from a technical level (limited protocol support on our cloud platform) or from the cost of an Enterprise licence.

Any assistance would be gratefully accepted...

Answer (score 0):

If you have an embedded Neo4j, you should know where in your code you are performing an update/create/delete query in Neo, no ?

To respond to your question, Neo4j has a `TransactionEventHandler` (https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html) that captures all the transaction and tells you what node/rel has been added, updated, deleted. 
In fact it's the way to implement triggers in Neo4j.

But in your case I will consider to :

- use another cloud provider that allow you to have a storage
- if not possible, to implement a hook on the application shutdown that copy the graph.db folder to a storage (do the opposite for the startup)
- use Neo4j as a remote server, and to install it on a cloud provider with a storage.